# Getting the results of an arXiv keyword search in my email

Tags: arxiv, online-publication

I'm not sure if this question would be more appropriate here or on SO. My hope is that someone has already had this need and found a solution.

Periodically, I search for a specific research topic on arXiv. Unfortunately it doesn't correspond to a specific arXiv subject: papers of interest can be found under very different subjects, since it's somewhat multidisciplinary. Currently, arXiv only supports sending periodic emails concerning either an entire archive, or one or more subjects inside an archive. There's no way I know of to receive only the results of a specific keyword search. However, I've heard of someone who has been able to get that, but I couldn't get them to explain me what they did.

Have you ever had this need? Did you find a solution?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, thanks, but I need the source to be arXiv. I already have a fairly comprehensive list of journals in my feed reader, which keeps me updated on published papers. However my sector is very competitive/rapidly evolving, and to keep up with the competition one needs to know about the good ideas as soon as possible. The average time to publication is between 1 and 2 years (!!!). Since all the good stuff (and most of the crappy stuff, too) is preprinted on arXiv, I need to keep abreast of those preprints!

Comment: ah, a Google *Scholar* alert! Ok. I thought you were referring to standard Google alerts, which I tried already with poor results. I think it will still index too much stuff (including stuff I already know about), but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's slightly more involved, but you can use the [the API](http://arxiv.org/help/api/index) to set up a script that does it for you. I recently asked [a question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/76020/subscribe-to-cross-listings-on-arxiv) trying to do something similar; I ended up going with a Python script that scraped the API and dumped the result to a local web page, stuck on a daily chron job. You could also set it to email the results to yourself (always be careful with how you set up the credentials!) You can find my code, as well as an outline of how to email it to yourself, in my answer to the above question.

Comment: Hey, apologies for forgetting to accept your answer! I had to toil quite a bit, but in the end I managed to make it work thanks to [this manual](http://arxiv.org/help/api/user-manual). It's fantastic! Precisely what I needed.

Comment: No worries; glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a [Google Scholar alert](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar_alerts?view_op=list_alerts). Google Scholar indexes, among other things, arXiv preprints (they typically take 2-3 days to show up), so you will get these in the email alerts.

Be warned that it also indexes journals, other repositories... And while it is possible to restrict advanced searches to arXiv, I haven't been able to set up an alert that only looks at arXiv. So if you are only interested in what shows up on the arXiv, you will have to weigh the pros and cons of also having alerts about papers you might already have seen elsewhere.

Comment: I do not trust google scholar alerts, there were some critical papers where it took a few weeks to get through to me.