# Subscribe to cross-listings on arXiv

Tags: publications, arxiv, online-publication

I'm interested in subscribing to cross-listings on the arXiv; similar to their [regular e-mail alerts](http://arxiv.org/help/subscribe), but with the caveat that I'm interested in papers cross-listed on both `quant-ph` and `cond-mat`. The majority of papers relevant to my research seem to be cross listed between those two one way or another.

I haven't found any way to do it through the arXiv subscription system; does a third party service exist? Is there a better way to zero in on these intersectional areas? Barring the existence of such a method, I may try to create my own; is there a stable API worth using?

Edit: Found [the API](http://arxiv.org/help/api/index), must have missed it earlier

Comment: Does your edit mean you've solved your own question?  If so, I strongly encourage you to post it as a self-answer, with a bit more explanation, so that others can benefit as well!

Comment: Not quite; namely, I was hoping to find a pre-existing solution (if one exists). If I give up and make my own I certainly will! The API is just something that I would need to do it.

Comment: One solution that came to mind (though I am unsure how easy it would be) is to use the rss feed from arXiv and get a feed reader to only present you with the intersection of what appears in the two feeds (though I am not familiar with a reader with this functionality build in unfortunately).

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of anyone who might want to do something similar in the future, I took a stab at making a script to fetch recent crosslisted submissions. I based it on the [example Python API parsing script](http://arxiv.org/help/api/examples/python_arXiv_parsing_example.txt). It's not perfect, but it will get the cross-lists which were posted within the 24 hours ending the previous day at 8pm (roughly corresponding to the /new/ page, except without the weekend aggregation). It also filters out the update submissions (as opposed to new submissions, which is what I'm primarily interested in).

Currently it prints out an HTML format, which is suitable for a web-page or e-mail. I set it up to run as a chron job and output to a local file, which I refresh on my browser; you could also set it up to email it to yourself every day, and I've included some commented code that would do that.

```
"""
Adapted from
http://arxiv.org/help/api/examples/python_arXiv_parsing_example.txt

with modifications by Alex Breitweiser

This is free software.  Feel free to do what you want
with it, but please play nice with the arXiv API!
"""

base_cat = "quant-ph"
cross_cats = {"cond-mat.str-el", "cond-mat.mes-hall"}

import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import feedparser
from datetime import date, timedelta
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Base api query url
base_url = 'http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?';

# Search parameters
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
dby = yesterday - timedelta(1)
start_date = dby.strftime("%Y%m%d")+"2000"
end_date = yesterday.strftime("%Y%m%d") + "2000"
search_query = 'cat:%s+AND+lastUpdatedDate:[%s+TO+%s]' % (base_cat,
                              start_date,
                              end_date)
start = 0                     # retreive the first 5 results
max_results = 50

query = 'search_query=%s&start=%i&max_results=%i' % (search_query,
                                                     start,
                                                     max_results)

# Opensearch metadata such as totalResults, startIndex, 
# and itemsPerPage live in the opensearch namespase.
# Some entry metadata lives in the arXiv namespace.
# This is a hack to expose both of these namespaces in
# feedparser v4.1
feedparser._FeedParserMixin.namespaces['http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/'] = 'opensearch'
feedparser._FeedParserMixin.namespaces['http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom'] = 'arxiv'

# perform a GET request using the base_url and query
response = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url+query).read()

# parse the response using feedparser
feed = feedparser.parse(response)

title = "New %s submissions cross listed on %s" % (base_cat, ", ".join(cross_cats))

body = "<h1>%s</h1>" % (title)

body += 'Feed last updated: %s' % feed.feed.updated

# Run through each entry, and print out information
for entry in feed.entries:
    all_categories = [t['term'] for t in entry.tags]
    if not any(cat in cross_cats for cat in all_categories):
        continue
    arxiv_id = entry.id.split('/abs/')[-1]
    if arxiv_id[-2:] != 'v1':
        continue
    pdf_link = ''
    for link in entry.links:
        if link.rel == 'alternate':
            continue
        elif link.title == 'pdf':
            pdf_link = link.href
    body += '<a href="%s"><h2>%s</h2></a>' % (pdf_link, entry.title)

    # feedparser v5.0.1 correctly handles multiple authors, print them all
    try:
        body += 'Authors:  %s</br>' % ', '.join(author.name for author in entry.authors)
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    try:
        comment = entry.arxiv_comment
    except AttributeError:
        comment = 'No comment found'
    body += 'Comments: %s</br>' % comment

    # Since the <arxiv:primary_category> element has no data, only
    # attributes, feedparser does not store anything inside
    # entry.arxiv_primary_category
    # This is a dirty hack to get the primary_category, just take the
    # first element in entry.tags.  If anyone knows a better way to do
    # this, please email the list!
    body += 'Primary Category: %s</br>' % entry.tags[0]['term']

    # Lets get all the categories
    all_categories = [t['term'] for t in entry.tags]
    body += 'All Categories: %s</br>' % (', ').join(all_categories)

    # The abstract is in the <summary> element
    body += '<p>%s</p>' %  entry.summary
    body += '</br>'
print(body)


'''
email = "foo@bar.com"
password = "f00bar!"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = title
msg['From'] = email
msg['To'] = email
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_port = 587
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.connect(smtp_host,smtp_port)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(email,password)
server.sendmail(user,tolist,msg.as_string())
'''
```